# The limit of the maximum number of values that can be stored in a multi-valued attribute in AD?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have a multivalued attribute of integer values in AD schema. The problem is that an AD object cannot be greater than 8 KB so it is not possible to store unlimited number of values in this attribute. In my case the practical limit is about 1200 values. What is the recommended approach in this kind of situations? I know that this AD schema is not the best one but I cannot rebuild it from the scratch.

I have the following ideas:

1. Split values of this attribute among more than one object and aggregate them on the program level. Program is written in C# and I can modify it easily. Possible but fairly nasty solution.
2. Use linked attributes which theoretically allow one to have an attribute with hundreds of thousands of values. However, according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677270%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) article a back link attribute (the one with hundreds of thousands of values) must be of type distinguished name (DS-DN) and I need integers (changing of data type is rather not possible).